# How can I make cmake search for the framework that is located in a user-defined location?

Tags: macos, frameworks, cmake

I am now trying to link jpeg framework in MAC with cmake. The problem is that it seems that CMake always search for the jpeg.framework in the system's path while it is supposed to link in a user-defined location. I use the following command to force cmake search the framework in a user-defined folder, but failed:

```
  target_link_libraries(${ProjectNameC} "-framework jpeg")

  set_target_properties(${ProjectNameC} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-F${user_defined_folder}")
```

I also tried this way:

```
   set_target_properties(${ProjectNameC} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-F${user_defined_folder} -framework jpeg")
```

Both solutions failed. I may use f`ind_library()`, but as the jpeg framework was created without any auxiliary file for `find_library()`. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find_package(JPEG required)` in conjunction with `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` (documented [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html)).

Note that it's best to avoid putting platform-specific things like `-framework` into your CMake files if possible, since it makes it difficult to generate working build systems on other platforms.